# FireBug: how to see what request sent? What does the server respond?

Tags: firebug

can anybody help me how to find the values that sent and respond? i am working on WCF services.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: By the way, HttpFox is useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example AJAX request when you go to google.com. The params tab will tell you what data was sent with the request.

[image]

Here's a view of the response.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Firebug Net Tab]

Expand the trees to see details.